# how to automate updation of data from mysql to logstash

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, logstash, webhooks

Currently i am working on Elastic Stack with Mysql, everything working fine like data in mysql database is available on Elastic-search using Logstash but when new data entered in mysql db then i need to restart Logstash or it can be done using Schedule in config file of Logstash

```
input {

  jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "ankit"
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "/home/ankit/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    #run logstash at an interval of on minute
    #schedule => "* * * * * *"
    # our query
    statement => "SELECT * FROM ghijkl"
    }
    jdbc { 
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb"
    # The user we wish to execute our statement as
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "ankit"
    # The path to our downloaded jdbc driver
    jdbc_driver_library => "/home/ankit/Downloads/mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    #run logstash at an interval of on minute
    #schedule => "* * * * * *"
    # our query
    statement => "SELECT * FROM abcdef"
    }
  }
```

but this isn't a good approach, and i am thinking to use web-hooks but no resource is available to do so, i tried Logstash HTTP input plugin from documentation page but no help from this.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can download only recent data let's say every 15 minutes using special query:

```
SELECT * FROM ghijkl" WHERE EVENT_TIME_OCCURRENCE_FIELD > :sql_last_value
```

In place of `:sql_last_value` a timestamp of the most recent record will be inserted . When the query is run for the first time `tracking_column` value is set to `01.01.1970`.

Required configuration for Logstash:

```
schedule => "*/15 * * * *"
use_column_value => true
tracking_column => 'EVENT_TIME_OCCURRENCE_FIELD'
```

For every input you should also specify `last_run_metadata_path` parameter in order to avoid problems in the future, when you have many inputs and some are using the same table but different schemas then meta data might be overridden and produce unexpected results.

```
last_run_metadata_path => "PATH_TO_FILE_FOR_META_DATA"
```

Comment: and what values can be assigned to EVENT_TIME_OCCURRENCE_FIELD

Comment: and i am looking for something like if some data inserted into mysql data then mysql can notify Logstash and using above method logstash checking for further updates that is costly method, are you getting my point

Comment: That's the most efficient method as long you have properly configured indexes. `WHERE EVENT_TIME_OCCURRENCE_FIELD > :sql_last_value` this condition is not a problem for DB with indexes. Even if you write your own script connected to Logstash using http etc. it will have to periodically check DB for new record with similar query, so overall it's just unnecessary complication.

Comment: It's usually a timestamp in a table, this column describes when a record was inserted to a DB. This column value is to be tracked by Logstash to deduce which records are new. When you don't any timestamp in your table then you can also use numeric field like for example id.

Comment: is there any method to notify Logstash from mysql when new data   entered in mysql

Comment: Of course there is but you will have to write your own app to take care of it. Do you really need your data from DB very quick? As long you don't need your data more frequent than 5-10 seconds and a DB table is not humongous then Logstash scheduled job won't overload your DB. Making your own notifier will take some time and it might be just a waste of time.